# C# - Is there anyway to add userdefined field to sort panel in View ribbon of Outlook?

Tags: outlook-addin

I have added a userproperty to an outlook folder and it can be displayed as a column in email list when the folder is selected.
Is it possible to add this field in to the "Sort group"/"Arange by" in View ribbon tab ?
Please take a look at the picture: http://screencast.com/t/aSJtdZhv